# What books should I purchase to start D&D4 with? (2014 after some became out of print)

Tags: dnd-4e

This is obviously a more difficult question to ask now, given 5th is on the way.

Essentials Dungeon Master Kit is way overpriced now, but the core rule books are still reasonably priced.

I don't care at all about premade campaigns or modules, I'd be making my own.

What player handbooks, rule books, dm guides, and monster books should I get for the most complete experience? (without having to pay over $150 for a complete set)

Comment: If you feel a question needs attention, earn some rep and place a bounty on it.

Comment: As @BrianBallsun-Stanton says, this question - http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/what-set-of-books-makes-a-complete-game?rq=1 is very similar to yours, and if it is only the fact that the information in its answers is out of date, the way to handle it on this site is to offer a bounty on the old question with a reason explaining why. Unfortunately, you require a certain amount of rep to be able to do that, so you won't be able to just yet.